# Printing vector in reverse order

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Is there a better way of printing a vector in reverse order then this:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

void print_elem(int elem)
{
    cout << elem << endl;    
}

int main()
{
    int ia[4]={1,2,3,4};
    vector<int> vec(ia,ia+4);
    reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),print_elem);
    reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

Comment: [`std::reverse_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many ways to print a bidirectional sequence in reverse without reversing the elements, e.g.:

```
std::copy(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
std::reverse_copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: +1 I was just writing up a response using `ostream_iterator`, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the reverse iterators:

```
for_each(vec.rbegin(),vec.rend(),print_elem);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `reverse_iterator` instead of `iterator`

```
int main()
{
    int ia[4]={1, 2, 3, 4};
    vector<int> vec(ia,ia+4);
    for(vector<int>::reverse_iterator it = vec.rbegin; it != vec.rend(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output will be: 4, 3, 2, 1

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.I will just explain one, more can be seen in [this](https://www.techiedelight.com/print-vector-reverse-order-cpp/) link.

Using constant reverse iterator(crbegin):

Reverse iterators iterate backward i.e increasing them moves them towards the beginning of the container.

To check if we have reached beginning, we can use the iterator variable(x in my case) to compare with crend (returns the starting of the vector).Remember everything is reverse here!

following is a simple implementation:

```
for(auto x = vec.crbegin() ; x!=vec.crend() ; x++){
        cout<<*x<<" ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 you can utilize [views::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/reverse_view) found in [ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) and [supported](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) by gcc 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{

        std::vector V{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        for (auto v : V | std::views::reverse)
        {
                std::cout << v << " ";
        }
        return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```